# The theory which axiomizes infinity.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

I met a strange question which gives me a Language L which only has one unary Relation R.(Set R) And it asks me to find an L-Theory which axiomizes the class of L-structure A where both R and A\R are infinite.

Is there really a way to describe infinite by those basic ->, =, etc + this R?

Comment: What is the basic $>$ or "etc"?

Comment: Is $->$ supposed to be logical implication? If so, you can get the symbol $\to$ by using \to in [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), which is the preferred way of typesetting mathematics on MSE.

Comment: HINT: we tend to think that an 'axiomitization' has to be finite, but that is not the case. So, your theory can contain infinitely many sentences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: design a sentence $\phi_n$ for $n = 1, 2, \ldots$ that says that $R$ contains at least $n$ distinct elements. E.g.,
$$
\phi_3 = \exists x_1, x_2, x_3(x_1 \neq x_2 \land x_1\neq x_3 \land x_2 \neq x_3 \land R(x_1) \land R(x_2) \land R(x_3))
$$

Similarly, design a sentence $\psi_n$ for $n = 1, 2, \ldots$ that says that $A \setminus R$ contains at least $n$ elements.

Now consider the theory $T=\{\phi_1, \psi_1, \phi_2, \psi_2, \ldots\}$. What can you say about $R$ and $A \setminus R$ in a model of $T$.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I've solved this. By the way, is there proof or explanation about why such a theory must be infinite? Aka, the "set R is infinite" can not be finitely axiomizable?

Comment: @qwerty Yes: if "R is infinite" is finitely axiomatizable, then so is its complement "R is finite". Now use the compactness theorem or ultraproducts to find a model of the theory "R is finite" in which R is infinite for a contradiction.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Sorry I don't get this. If R is infinite is finitely axiomatizable, it will be {a1,a2...an} finitely many sentences in that theory, so the R is finite should has the axiom theory {not a1 or not a2... or not an}. simply based on this, how can I raise what I want? And so what is the connection between finitely axiomizable？

Comment: @qwerty That's right. Now use compactness to get a model of the latter sentence in which R is infinite. How? Consider the theory consisting of your "$R$ is finite" sentence together with all of the sentences $\phi_n$ from Rob Arthan's answer. I'm afraid this is as good of a proof sketch as I can give you in a comment - if you don't follow it, I suggest you ask a new question.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Sorry I must forget some key knowledge and I can not follow, so if you are wiling to explain, please goto this new question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3941920/728707