# How to show "a set which is infinite" can not be finitely axiomatized?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

I met a strange question which gives me a Language L which only has one unary Relation R.(Set R) My concern is how to prove that the theory which axiomatizes "R is infinite" can not be finite.

We know that the theory which axiomatizes "R is infinite" can be something like {R has at least 1 element, R has at least 2 elements... etc} which is infinite. But not sure if it can be done with finite sentences.

So generally how-to, I suppose, use compactness theorem to show that "R is infinite" can not be finitely axiomatized?

A previous relevant question is: [The theory which axiomizes infinity.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3941424/728707)

Comment: In fact, by compactness, "R is finite" cannot be axiomatized at all, even by an infinite set of sentences! It follows from this that "R is infinite" cannot be *finitely* axiomatized. I don't have time right now to write a full answer - someone else will surely do it in the meantime, and if not, I'll come back later. You should include the link to your previous question, which is highly relevant.

Comment: I have a question, the key problem now is, why if <"R is infinite" can be finitely axiomatized> will lead to <"R is finite" can be (finitely) axiomatized> but <"R is infinite" can be infinitely axiomatized> can not even lead to  <"R is finite" can be  axiomatized>? If we took the whole negation of theory which tells "R is infinite", (infinitely many or), wouldn't we get a theory telling "R is finite"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can easily spell out "$|R|\le n$" for any fixed $n$, namely $$\exists x_1\ldots \exists x_n \forall y\colon y\in R\to (y=x_1\lor\cdots \lor y=x_n).$$
Hence we also can formulate $|R|> n$
assume we can spell out some $|R|<\infty$. Then the infinitely many sentences
$$ |R|<\infty,|R|> 1, |R|> 2,|R|> 3,\ldots $$
cannot have a model. By compactness, hence some finite subset has no model. But any such finite subset just amounts to $$n<|R|<\infty$$ for some $n$. Now exhibit a model where $R$ is finite but larger than $n$ to arrive at a contradiction.

Comment: Sorry I made a typo about the question, actually, I want to know why the sentence that "R is infinite" can not be finitely axiomizable.

Comment: @qwerty: If ‘$R$ is infinite’ could be finitely axiomatized, so could ‘$R$ is finite’, and Hagen has shown that this is impossible.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Here, why ‘R is infinite’ could be infinitely axiomatized won't lead to the same problem? If I take the negation of the infinite axioms (theory), I'll get a infinite "or" set, which should be the theory of R is finite, right?

Comment: @qwerty: You can’t form an infinite disjunction.